# How can i use a common header in Cognos among many report pages?

Tags: report, business-intelligence, cognos

I have a Cognos report and i have created 3 pages and 1 common prompt page. According to a radio selection in the prompt page i show the appropriate among these 3 pages.

In each page i have a block that is the header and there i just show title, current date and the selected values of the prompt controls (parameter values).

This header is the same among all pages and i want to find a way to create only 1 header section and then assign it on the top of each page. So if later i want to change anything in the header i will do it in one place.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-using parts of a report (either from the report or other report in Cognos Connection) can be achieved with the help of *layout component refenrences* which are inserted into your report page and which refer to other existing components.

To use them proceed as follows:

1. Indentify the layout component(s) to be re-used (e.g. a table or a text or more or less anything less).
2. In the property list of that component go to the `name` and give it a unique name.
3. In the report page that is supposed to re-use the component drag an instance of the *layout component reference* to the appropriate location in the page.
4. Specify the target of the reference by choosing the report and within the report the named component (same name as given above).

**Example**

A block component (which could be incorporated into a header) is to be re-used. Give the block a name, e.g. `my_block`:

[image: name property of component to be re-used]

From the toolbox drag the *layout component reference*

[image: layout component reference toolbox icon]

to the report page. A dialog box opens which permits choosing the target component:

[image: dialog box for choosing the target of the layout component reference]